# Totally non parallelizable manifold

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Does there exist a  manifold  M   which  all iterated tangent bundles  are  non parallelizable  manifolds? That is$ M, TM , T^2(M), \ldots ,T^n(M)\ldots$  are  non parallelizable  manifold?

What is  an  example  of  a  manifold which is  not  parallelizable, but $T^{n}(M)$ is  parallelizable  for  some  n?

Comment: This is equivalent to the question "Does parallelizability of $TM$ implies parallelizability of $M$?" applied to $T^{n-1}M$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\xi$ is a vector bundle over a manifold $B$ with total space $E(\xi)$, then the restriction of $TE(\xi)$ to the the zero section of $\xi$ is isomorphic to $\xi\oplus TB$. It follows that $T^k M$ restricted to $T^{k-1}M$ is isomorphic to $T^{k-1}M\oplus T^{k-1}M$, and iterating we conclude that $T^k M$ restricted to $M$ is the sum of $2^{k-1}$ copies of $TM$. Thus $TM$ is non-torsion in the group $(KO(M), \oplus)$ if and only if $T^kM$ is nontrivial for all $k$. The simplest example of a manifold with non-torsion tangent bundle is $M=CP^2$.

Comment: Igor, could you explain something in your answer? First, why is it valid to restrict $TE(\xi)$ to the 0-section of $\xi$ for the purpose of answering the question, i.e. how one would show that $TE(\xi)$ parallelizable iff the 0-section is? The reason I am asking is that it's possible apriori that parallelizability is not stable property relative to direct sum with a trivial bundle.

Comment: @Michael, I never claimed that $TE(\xi)$ is parallelizable iff its $0$-section is (this is false, think of $S^2$). The point is that a rank $k$ vector bundle $\xi$ over $B$ is a homotopy class of maps $B\to BO(k)$, so if $B$ deformation retracts to $S$, then $\xi$ is completely determined (up to isomorphism) by its restriction to $S$.

Comment: I see. In particular, Stiefel-Whitney of $TTM$ would be 0, therefore $TTM$ is always orientable. Could you remind me the criterion of parallelizability?

Comment: @Igor thank you very much for your beautiful answer. you said "think of S^2" do you mean TS^2 is parallelizable?

Comment: @Michael: criterion? By definition, a manifold is parallelizable iff its tangent bundle is trivial.

Comment: @Igor Is $TS^{2}$ ot $T^{2} S^{2}$ a counterexample to the last part of my question?

Comment: @Ali: yes, $TS^2$ is parallelizable. In general, an open manifold is parallelizable iff it is stably parallelizable. As I explained $T(TS^2)$ is $2TS^2$ in $K$-theory, but $TS^2$ is stably trivial, and hence so is $2TS^2$. Hence $S^2$ answers your second question.

Comment: @Igor Why for open manifold, stable parallelizable imply parallelizable?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, by criterion I meant something computable, such as a certain characteristic class vanishing. It cannot be Euler class = 0 because of $S^5$, for example.

Comment: @Igor another question: why the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ is  a non torsion element in real K theory?

Comment: Ali: because an open manifold is homotopy equivalent to a complex of lower dimension. Michael: there is no criterion of parallelizability in terms of characteristic classes. Ali: $CP^2$ has nonzero first Pontryagin class. Actually, what you ask are good exercises. You should do them yourself.

Comment: @Igor perhaps this is an alternative proof for parallelizability of $TS^{2}$:According to your statements it is sufficient to prove $TS^{2} \oplus TS^{2} $ is  a trivial bundle on $S^{2}. But this  a  consequence of the fact "the complexification of tangent bundle of spheres is trivial", this is said in Sawans paper "f.g projective module and vector bundles" But what is  a proof for this statement of Swan's paper?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Just  now I realized that perhaps something is missing in your answer. If $E$ is  a n_vector bundle on  a k-manifold $M$ then $TE$ (and its restriction to every subset) is a 2n- bundle. How a 2n-bundle can be isomorphic to a n+2k bundle $E\oplus TM$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek In my previous comment I have to write "n+k" not "n+2k".

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I do not follow what you wrote: if $E$ is $\mathbb R^n$-bundle over $k$-manifold, then $E$ has dimension $n+k$, so $TE$ is an $\mathbb R^{n+k}$-bundle.

Comment: Can you delete your earlier comment, and write the one with all dimensions correct?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek  assume that $E$ is a n dimensional vector bundle on a k dimensional manifold $M$. Then TE is a 2n dimensional vectoe bundle on $TM$.(Note that we do NOT consider $TE$ as a vector bundle on $E$. But we consider $TE$ as  a vector bundle on $TM$. So $TE$ is a 2n dimensional bundle on $TM$(Independent of k!)No my question: How the 2n-bundle TE (restricted to the zero section of TM) is isomorphic to n+k bundle $E\oplus TM$? I think that some thing is missing in your answer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Sorry, I still do not understand what you mean. You seem to confuse the bundle $TE$ and its total space. The total space of $TE$ has dimension $2(n+k)$. The bundle $TE$ restricted to any subset of $E$ has fiber dimension $n+k$. You could consider $TM$ as a submanifold of $TE$ but not of $E$, so it make sense to talk about the normal bundle of the submanifold $TM$ in the manifold $TE$, but not of the restriction of the bundle $TE$ to the subset $TM$. When you get the terminology straight it would be easier for me to see the issue.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek In order to remove misunderestanding, lets review the proof of the fact  'IF  (E,M,p) is a n-bundle then (TE,TM,Dp) is a 2n-bundle, where(It is not important what is dim of M). Assume that E is trivial over$U\subset M$. Then $TE$ is trivial on $TU$, because

Comment: ....because$Dp^{-1}(TU)=Tp^{-1}(U)\simeq T(U\times \mathbb{R}^{n})\simeq TU\times T\mathbb{R}^{n} \simeq TU\times \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. So $(TE,TM,Dp)$ is trivial on $TU$ and the dimension of fibre is equal to 2n. (no matter what dim(M) is)

Comment: I learnt it from chapter 11 (Connection) of "Lecture on differentiable manifolds" by Siavash Shahshahani.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13137/discussion-between-igor-belegradek-and-ali-taghavi)

Comment: @IgorBelegradek sorry there is software problem in my computer system(For chat).may be continue in this comment page?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I apologize for my misunderestanding. Now I underestand you consider $TE$ as a vector bundle on $E$  not as a vector bundle on $TM$.Thanks again for your answer.