# Is the unit tangent bundle of $S^{n}$ parallelizable?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Is the unit tangent bundle of $S^{n}$ a  parallelizable  manifold.  This  is motivated by the fact that $TS^{n}$ is parallelizable?

Comment: I thought the tangent bundle $TS^n$ is parallelizable if and only if $n\in\{1;3;7\}$. For $n$ even you won't even find a nowhere vanishing vector field on $S^n$!

Comment: A simple google search with the question which spheres are parallelizable    yielded this paper of Bott.  http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1958-64-03/S0002-9904-1958-10166-4/S0002-9904-1958-10166-4.pdf

Comment: @TommasoCenteleghe  However $S^{n}$ is  not parallelizable for almost all $n$ but its tangent bundle is always parallizable. see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151676/totally-non-parallelizable-manifold?rq=1)

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  I am not talking about  sphere. I talk about the unit tangent bundle of sphere

Comment: @AliTaghavi, it would probably help to mention the ambiguity that naturally arises here. You might include your qualification in the statement of the question.

Comment: @PeterCrooks  I consider $M=$ the unit tangent bundle of $S^{n}$. Is  $M$, as a  manifold,  parallelizable? Note that there is  no  a primary obstruction since the euler charactristic iz $0=0\times 2$

Comment: @PeterCrooks  I think my question is  not unclear. what is  the unclear point?

Comment: @PeterCrooks  according to your first  comment: It is true that $TS^{2}$ is  not  a  trivial  bundle. But it is  not true that $TS^{2}$ is  not parallelizable (As  a  **manifold**)

Comment: The unit tangent bundle of the 2-sphere is parallelisable. In fact, every orientable 3-manifold is parallelisable. The latter can be proven by Computing $w_2=0$.

Comment: It's also parallelisable for $n=1,3,7$, since in this case your manifold is a product of spheres, one of which is odd-dimensional (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52871/does-a-trivial-tangent-bundle-induce-a-multiplication/59851#59851 )

Comment: I would like to second Peter Crooks's suggestion.  You are literally asking if a *bundle* is parallelizable, which usually is interpreted as the question of if the *bundle* is trivial.  But as we can see, you are talking about the *total space* of the bundle, if that is parallelizable as a manifold.  You should re-word your question, and the title.

Comment: @RyanBudney (and Peter Crooks):  I don't think you are using language in a standard way.  The statement that "$M$ is parallelizable" always (as far as I'm aware) means that the tangent bundle to $M$ is trivial.   I've never (outside of your comments) seen "parallelizable" used to mean "trivial a as a vector bundle".

Comment: When referring to a bundle, yes that's what it means. In reference to a manifold, sure it is talking about the tangent bundle of that manifold.

Comment: The unit tangent bundle of a sphere is usually just called a Stiefel manifold (of 2-frames).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

W.Sutherland.  A note on the parallelizability of sphere bundles over sphere. J. London Math. Soc. 39 (1964), 55--62.

The answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your answer  and the reference.